# Search/Replace (in an XML-File) the value of one attribute if another attribute has a specific value

Tags: notepad++

My XML File (~6000 lines) contains lines like these:

```
<sms protocol="0" address="+12341234" date="12341234" type="2" subject="null" body="smstext" toa="0" sc_toa="0" service_center="+12341234" read="1" status="-1" locked="0" date_sent="null" readable_date="Jan 6, 1980 1:02:14 AM" contact_name="Patrick" />
```

and i want to replace the text of contact_name with something else, but only if type="2".

I mean it would be very easy if i could bookmark all the type="2" lines and then search/replace on the bookmarked lines only, but i haven't found such an option.

So how would i do that in Notepad++?

EDIT: changed the title, i meant attribute not tag ...

Comment: A larger data set would be useful to better see what format the data is in (Are the fields within the <SMS > tags always the same sequence, are there multiple records on a line, are there multi-line tags etc).

Comment: @TimRadcliffe except for the xml header there are only <sms> tag lines, there are no multi-line tags and there are NOT multiple records on one line. They are basicly all the same except for different attribute values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try following:

Find: `(?<=type="2")(.*?)(contact_name=")(.*?)(")`

Replace with: `\1\2SomeOtherContactName\4`

`(?<=type="2")` let's you see if string contains type="2", but not capturing string

`(.*?)` is a first group between type and contact name (any symbol)

`(contact_name=")` - is a second group

`(.*?)` group #3 wicth you want to replace with some other value (any symbol, or can look like `[A-Za-z]`

`(")` - just contains closing quote. And we use it as group 4 in replace statement

Comment: thx worked exactly as i wanted :) (after setting search mode to Regular Expression)