# How to search and replace a particular attribute in an XML Node using Notepad++

Tags: xml, replace, notepad++

Using Notepad++, Can I search a particular attribute in an XML

```html
<Funtionality1>
<IsActive>true</IsActive>
<Text1>Sample</Text1>
<Module>Sample</Module>
</Funtionality1>
<Funtionality2>
<IsActive>true</IsActive>
<Text1>Sample1</Text1>
<Text2>Sample2</Text2>
<Text3>Sample3</Text3>
</Funtionality2>
<Funtionality3>
<IsActive>true</IsActive>
</Funtionality3>
```

In he above code, I need to search only for IsActive as true under Functionality2 and replace them as false

Answer (score 2):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `<Funtionality2>\R<IsActive>\Ktrue`
- Replace with: `false`
- *check Wrap around*
- *check Regular expression*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
<Funtionality2> : literally
\R              : any kind of linebreak
<IsActive>      : literally
\K              : forget all we have seen until this position
true            : literally
```

**Result for given example:**

```
<Funtionality1>
<IsActive>true</IsActive>
<Text1>Sample</Text1>
<Module>Sample</Module>
</Funtionality1>
<Funtionality2>
<IsActive>false</IsActive>
<Text1>Sample1</Text1>
<Text2>Sample2</Text2>
<Text3>Sample3</Text3>
</Funtionality2>
<Funtionality3>
<IsActive>true</IsActive>
</Funtionality3>
```

Answer (score 1):

With **Notepad+ +** you can use the search option to replace certain values;
Open the replace dialog **(Ctrl+H)** and select at the bottom "**Regular expressions**".
Find: `<([^ >]) "(.)"/>`
Replace: `<\1>\2`
See this post for more info on how to use these syntaxes: [Search/Replace XML Attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17746089/search-replace-in-an-xml-file-the-value-of-one-attribute-if-another-attribute)
 There is also something else you can try; hold your **Alt-key** while dragging with the mouse to select a square, (or **alt+shift+arrow keys**)then press delete.
See this example: [Deleting Data](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/features/column-mode-editing.html)

Comment: Thanks Hasan. The other Link Search/Replace can help, but I find difficult to understand, if that could do for a particular node, as I need to also use the option Replace lot of XML files in my directory too.

Answer (score 0):

Press CTL-F and enter the text to find in the search text box.  You can select whether to to treat the string as case-sensitive and as a whole word.

Comment: Thanks John. But I would need only the attribute active as true to false to be changed only for Functionality2. Functionality1 and Functionality3 needs to remain with Active as true